# Oracle 11g connection throws mysterious exception

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Our application is based on Oracle 11g database. Its drivers are already installed but application throws an error on runtime.

> "AppliMSP.ADOcommands.GetConnected
>   Error while connecting,
>   Provider cannot be found, It may not be properly installed."

I am using OraOLEDB.oracle provider. This provider works properly on ANother module (Administration) 
of this application but as I want to connect as client with same name and password I get above error.

I have tried with MSDAORA(Oracle) but I don't get any success.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

go to your 11g db and
alter system set `sec_case_sensitive_logon=false`